# Check if swift array does not contain object

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I'm trying to filter a list of users from a Firebase query so that I only get users that are NOT listed in one of two arrays. The code I'm using doesn't work:

```
   let users = snapshot.childSnapshots.map {
                User(snapshot: $0)
            }.filter{
                guardiansArray.contains($0.key) == false || dependentsArray.contains($0.key) == false
        }
```

If I remove the `==false` code, I get the opposite effect of what I want: I get a list of users that ARE in either of the two arrays. How can I get the reverse effect?

Thanks!

Comment: `!guardiansArray.contains($0.key) && !dependentsArray.contains($0.key)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use `&&` instead of `||`.